# How do we find a biggest white rectangle in a n x n bitmap ? 

Tags: c++

Any idea on how to solve such problems (in C++)-
like which is the best Algorithm to use.

Comment: How about putting some example cases so that we can better understand the question?

Comment: How many colors? Is it paletted? Does it use a certain colour space? Is the rectangle always axis aligned, or can it be rotated?
I kind of assume that 'bitmap' means an image with pixel data. Please clarify and tell us whether this is the case or not.

Comment: is the white area rectangle shaped or is it an arbitrary shaped white area where you want to find the biggest rectangle that fits in?

Comment: I have just signed to SO for a homework question and as a result, all of you have to do whatever I want :-)

Answer (score 3):

Say you have a n x n rectangular area black and white (O and 1) pixels and you're looking for the biggest white rectangle in this area.

I would write something simple like below:

- first pass: create a set of 1 line segments for each pixel row.
- second pass aggregate rectangles:

  - for each segment iterate on rows to find the largest rectangle containing it.
  - if you use another segment in the process mark it as used, not need to try it again
  - at any point keep only the largest rectangle found

That's only a first draft of a possible solution. It should be rewritten using a more formal algorithmic syntax and many details should be provided. Each step hides pitfalls to avoid if you want to be efficient. But it should not be too hard to code.

If I did not missed something, what I described above should basically be O(n4) in the worst case, with the first pass O(n2) used to find horizontal segments (could be quite fast with a very small loop) and the second pass probably much less thant O(n4) in practice (depends on segment size, really is nb_total_segment x nb_segment_per_line x nb_overlapping_segment).

That looks not bad to me. Can't see any obvious way to do it with better O complexity, (but of course there may be some way, O(n4) is not that good).

If you provide some details on input structure and expected result it may even be some fun to code.

Answer (score 2):

What you ask for is known as *blob filtering* on the computer vision world.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_extraction
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_labeling
- http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/blobs_processing.html

Comment: More details of this question - 
use-case : when a image is captured,we get it as a bitmap - task is to find the biggest white rectangle in this image.

say there is a bitmap (coloured) it is n x n always, im thining what will be the good way to work on such problems.

kriss - your understanding is right ,thanks for your response